# The same python binary in two different terminals sees a different environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gcc

I tried to run a jupyter notebook cell in vscode today and got

```
"Running cells with 'Python 3.10.6 64-bit' requires ipykernel package".
```

This is very strange, as my Jupiter laptop environment was still working yesterday. Also, I see all the python packages in their place. The only thing that has changed is that last night I updated the system packages through Pop!_Shop (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS).

Running `python3.10` I noticed that the version of the GCC inside the vscode terminal is different from the one in the system terminal. How is this even possible when the `which` command shows that the path to the binary is the same? Then I checked `gcc --version` itself and to my surprise the same thing happened to it.

from vscode terminal

[image: from vscode terminal]

from system terminal

[image: from system terminal]

`sys.path` in both terminals is the same, but one sees packages, for example `requests`, and the other does not.

I am sure that the original problem with the jupyter cell is related to this, because ipykernel is also in the sys.path, which is somehow inaccessible to the vscode's terminal and maybe jupyter extension.

For Jupyter I can switch to one of the venvs, where the problem disappears. But the magic with the binary in the terminals remains unclear.

**EDIT:**

The problem was solved by uninstalling the flatpak version of vscode and installing the fresh deb package from the official site. Now in vscode terminal I have the same compiler version as in the system terminal and the modules are found without problems, including `ipykernel`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the comment, I somehow did not pay attention to the answer acceptance feature before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to reinstall vscode with deb package from official website. See the edited part of the question.